# imagesLoaded plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my attempt, which is not working. It fires, but imagesloaded does not 'fade in'

Jsfiddle attached: http://jsfiddle.net/NgwTa/

```
    var insert = "<div class='thediv'><img src='http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gallery/mercedes-c63-amg-black-series-tuned-by-vath-photo-gallery_9.jpg'></div><br><div class=thediv><img src='http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gallery/mercedes-c63-amg-black-series-tuned-by-vath-photo-gallery_9.jpg'></div>";


$('.clickit').click(function(){

    $('.container').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('.box').html(insert);
    });


});
```

Comment: Hide .box class with CSS, instead of hiding it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are asking the container if all your images have loaded ***before*** any images have been appended. Therefore the function is running instantaneously.

Try running your imagesLoaded plugin after the append.

Fade in after all images have loaded:

```
$('.clickit').click(function(){

    // Hide the box and insert the images
    $('.box').hide().append(insert);

    // Wait for the images to load
    $('.container').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('.box').fadeIn();
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2684/

Fade individual images as they load:

```
$('.clickit').click(function(){

    $('.box').append(insert);
    $('.thediv img').hide();

    $('.container').imagesLoaded().progress(function(instance, image){
        $(image.img).fadeIn();
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2684/1/

Comment: this fades in all .box, it doesn't handle the images individually

Comment: Then you'll need to run the `fadeIn` on the `progress` event. See my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

imagesloaded plugin is not for fading images. It just throws a callback when an image has been loaded to your browser.

Yo need to add an extra line on your css to hide the images first.

```
.thediv img {
width:300px;
height:200px;
display:none}
```

Then include a fadeIn to your image on your script.

```
$('.clickit').click(function(){

    $('.container').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('.box').html(insert);
        $('.thediv img').fadeIn();
    });


});
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stringtheory80/NgwTa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Look this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgwTa/2/)

Code:

```
var insert = "<div class='thediv'><img src='http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gallery/mercedes-c63-amg-black-series-tuned-by-vath-photo-gallery_9.jpg'></div><br><div class=thediv><img src='http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gallery/mercedes-c63-amg-black-series-tuned-by-vath-photo-gallery_9.jpg'></div>";

$('.clickit').click(function(){

    $('.container').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('.box').hide().html(insert).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

You have to declare the `fadeIn()` and `hide()` first and the can you set the result into a `fadeIn()`

Comment: Better to hide it with a plain CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way

```
   $('.clickit').click(function(){
        $('.box').html(insert);
        $('.container img').load(function(){
              $('.container').fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
```

on jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/NgwTa/6/
```

Comment: this is not a solution to the plugin listed in the example